# Weui hyperlink doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, zepto

I am using weui and zepto.js to create an Android app, the hyperlink works on my PC but not on Android. The code is as follows:

```
> <a href="input" class="weui-tabbar__item">   <img
> src="./images/icon_nav_panel.png" alt=""  class="weui-tabbar__icon"> 
> <p class="weui-tabbar__label">Go</p>  
> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            yourTextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(HtmlText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
        } else {
            yourTextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(HtmlText));
        }
```